# Parsing json with AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, json, asynctaskloader

I'm trying to use AsyncTaskLoader to retrieve data then parse the resulting json file, however, I can't figure out why I keep getting a

> return null;

instead of returning

> return gameList;

**DailyScheduleFragment.java**

Method calling the Loader:

```
    public void loadGameScheduleList() {

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID_DAILY_SCHEDULE, null, new LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<Game>>() {

        public Loader<ArrayList<Game>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            return new DailyScheduleLoader(DailyScheduleFragment.this.getContext());
        }

        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<Game>> loader, ArrayList<Game> data) {
            if (data == null) {
                Exception exception = ((DailyScheduleLoader) loader).getException();
                if (exception == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (exception instanceof NoNetworkException) {
                    DailyScheduleFragment.this._btnMessage.setText(R.string.general_msg_no_network_connection_turn_on);
                    DailyScheduleFragment.this._btnMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intents.networkSettings(DailyScheduleFragment.this.getContext());
                        }
                    });
                    DailyScheduleFragment.this._progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    DailyScheduleFragment.this._btnMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return;
                }
                DailyScheduleFragment.this._btnMessage.setText(R.string.general_msg_something_went_wrong);
                DailyScheduleFragment.this._btnMessage.setOnClickListener(null);
                DailyScheduleFragment.this._progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                DailyScheduleFragment.this._btnMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return;
            }
            DailyScheduleFragment.this._games.clear();
            Iterator it = data.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                DailyScheduleFragment.this._games.add((Game) it.next());
            }
            DailyScheduleFragment.this._adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            DailyScheduleFragment.this.displayListState();
        }

        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<Game>> loader) {
        }
    }).forceLoad();
}
```

**DailyScheduleLoader.java**

```
public class DailyScheduleLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<Game>> {

private Context _context;
private Exception _exception;

public DailyScheduleLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this._context = context;
}

public ArrayList<Game> loadInBackground() {

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this._context);

    try {
        ArrayList<Game> gameList = Parse.gameList(Networking.sendHttpRequest("http://api.sportradar.us/nhl/trial/v5/en/games/2018/01/01/schedule.json?api_key=xxx", this._context));

        return gameList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this._exception = e;
        return null;
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public Exception getException() {
    return this._exception;
}
```

**Network** class:

```
public static final class Networking {

    public static String sendHttpRequest(String urlString, Context context) throws Throwable {
        NoNetworkException e;
        Exception ex;
        Throwable th;
        if (urlString == null || urlString.trim().equals(BuildConfig.FLAVOR)) {
            throw new NullPointerException("urlString");
        }
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = null;
        InputStream input_stream = null;
        InputStreamReader input_stream_reader = null;
        BufferedReader input = null;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlString).openConnection();
                if (httpCon.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "Cannot Connect to : " + urlString);
                    if (input == null) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    try {
                        input_stream_reader.close();
                        input_stream.close();
                        input.close();
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (httpCon == null) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    httpCon.disconnect();
                    return null;
                }
                input_stream = httpCon.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader input_stream_reader2 = new InputStreamReader(input_stream);
                try {
                    BufferedReader input2 = new BufferedReader(input_stream_reader2);
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            String line = input2.readLine();
                            if (line == null) {
                                break;
                            }
                            response.append(line).append("\n");
                        } catch (Exception e4) {
                            ex = e4;
                            input = input2;
                            input_stream_reader = input_stream_reader2;
                        } catch (Throwable th2) {
                            th = th2;
                            input = input2;
                            input_stream_reader = input_stream_reader2;
                        }
                    }
                    if (input2 != null) {
                        try {
                            input_stream_reader2.close();
                            input_stream.close();
                            input2.close();
                        } catch (IOException e22) {
                            e22.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (httpCon != null) {
                            httpCon.disconnect();
                            input = input2;
                            input_stream_reader = input_stream_reader2;
                            return response.toString();
                        }
                    }
                    input_stream_reader = input_stream_reader2;
                } catch (Exception e6) {
                    ex = e6;
                    input_stream_reader = input_stream_reader2;
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    if (input != null) {
                        try {
                            input_stream_reader.close();
                            input_stream.close();
                            input.close();
                        } catch (IOException e222) {
                            e222.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (httpCon != null) {
                            httpCon.disconnect();
                        }
                    }
                    return response.toString();
                } catch (Throwable th4) {
                    th = th4;
                    input_stream_reader = input_stream_reader2;
                    if (input != null) {
                        try {
                            input_stream_reader.close();
                            input_stream.close();
                            input.close();
                        } catch (IOException e2222) {
                            e2222.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (httpCon != null) {
                            httpCon.disconnect();
                        }
                    }
                    throw th;
                }
                return response.toString();
            }
            throw new NoNetworkException();
        } catch (NoNetworkException e7) {
            e = e7;
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e8) {
            ex = e8;
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (input != null) {
                input_stream_reader.close();
                input_stream.close();
                input.close();
                if (httpCon != null) {
                    httpCon.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return response.toString();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(@NonNull Context context) {
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService("connectivity")).getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

**Parse** class:

```
    public static class Parse {

    public static ArrayList<Game> gameList(String json) throws JSONException {

        ArrayList<Game> games = new ArrayList();
        JSONArray results = new JSONObject(json).getJSONArray("games");

        // looping through All Games
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject gameJSON = results.getJSONObject(i);

            Game game = new Game();

            game.setId(gameJSON.getString(Responses.Games.VALUE_ID));
            game.setStatus(gameJSON.getString(Responses.Games.VALUE_STATUS));

            games.add(game);
        }
        return games;
    }
}
```

I found the code on a website and trying to modify it to suit my needs. For the most part, it works well, except I can't figure out where I'm going wrong with this.

If it helps, here's the json file that's returned in the request (sorry about the formatting):

> {"date":"2018-01-01","league":{"id":"fd560107-a85b-4388-ab0d-655ad022aff7","name":"NHL","alias":"NHL"},"games":[{"id":"6d20bdbd-b5e0-46ab-8b98-45ea01ab0e2b","status":"scheduled","coverage":"full","scheduled":"2018-01-01T18:00:00+00:00","reference":"20601","venue":{"id":"faebd24e-ccfb-4e7c-aa58-1dee9e82bb0f","name":"Citi Field","capacity":45000,"address":"123 Roosevelt Ave","city":"Queens","state":"NY","zip":"11368","country":"USA","time_zone":"US/Eastern"},"broadcast":{"network":"NBC"},"home":{"id":"4416d559-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44","name":"Buffalo Sabres","alias":"BUF"},"away":{"id":"441781b9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44","name":"New York Rangers","alias":"NYR"}}]}

Go [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) if you want it formatted.

I've added break points and stepped through the code to check the variables. All seems right, up until the

```
return gameList;
```

Comment: Your code looks okay. Still, try to debug your code. Use break points to check the values of each variables.

Comment: What are you using for network request ? Mind posting `sendHttpRequest()`?

Comment: I posted some updates to the code above including the Network class, etc. Any ideas on where my problem is?

Comment: Don't add 'Solved' to the title. The proper way to mark a question as solved is to provide an answer and accept it.